# When selecting category, display both elements of category and elements of all subcategories

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. I am practicing creating an online store. I'm facing this problem: When choosing a category, it would be logical to also display products from all its subcategories.

Unfortunately, Google did not help. I think that you need to somehow correctly filter the product in the views, but how? My skills are not enough to understand. I'm using Django-mptt for the category tree (fewer database queries).

For example, there are such categories:

- Clothing

  - Jackets
  - Hats

If the product is in the "Jackets" category and we go into this category, everything is fine, but if we go to "Clothes" then it will be empty, but you need to have all the products from both the "Jackets" category and from the "Hats".

Now the sorting of products is obtained only by the category that was selected when adding the product.

**models.py**

```py
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```py
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/shop.html',
                  {'category': category,
                  'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})
```

**html**

```
<div class="category_conteiner">
{% recursetree categories %}
    <div class="sub_menu_category">
        <a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}" class="subcatbtn">{{ node.name }}</a>
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
        <div class="subcat_content">
            <div class="subcat_column">
                {{ children }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div> 
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in an extra step. You need to get child categories and then filter products by them.
Example code:

```
category = Category.objects.get(category_slug=category_slug)
sub_categories = category.get_descendants(include_self=True)
Product.objects.filter(category__in=sub_categories)
```

And here is the full code for your case.

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        sub_categories = category.get_descendants(include_self=True)
        products = products.filter(category__in=sub_categories)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/shop.html',
                  {'category': category,
                  'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})
```